# I got this error- IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, numpy, split, append

I want to load `numpy` files to feed into CNN but I got this `IndexError`. I don't know why `preictalSpectograms[cont].append(line.split(' ')[2].rstrip()) IndexError: list index out of range` .

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 while(line.strip()!=""):
        print('linex: ', line)
        print('\n')
        if("SEIZURE" in line):
            line=f.readline()
            if(len(line.split(' '))>=3):
                preictalSpectograms.append([])
                cont=cont+1
                preictalSpectograms[cont].append(line.split(' ')[2].rstrip())
                indFilePathRead=indFilePathRead+1
        else:
            if(len(line.split(' '))>=3):
                preictalSpectograms[cont].append(line.split(' ')[2].rstrip())
            indFilePathRead=indFilePathRead+1
```

Comment: my guess is that whatever number appears in cont is larger than the size of preictalSpectograms

Comment: Please provide a [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That line has two list index operations, `preictalSpectograms[cont]` and `line.split(' ')[2]`.  Your job is to identify which is giving problems.  The previous `if` line should protect against problems with the 2nd (but why are you splitting twice?).  In that case `cont` must be off.  Are you appending to `preictalSpectograms` itself, or to a list inside it?  You need to test that block of code line by line, iteration by iteration.  Don't guess as to what's happening.  Test, print, test and print again!

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by `numpy files`?  Are they `csv` format text?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted all the relevant code it's hard to give you a guaranteed solution but my guess is that you are incrementing `cont` before even doing the first `append()` call so you actually never append to the first item in the list.

```
while(line.strip()!=""):
        print('linex: ', line)
        print('\n')
        if("SEIZURE" in line):
            line=f.readline()
            if(len(line.split(' '))>=3):
                preictalSpectograms.append([])
                preictalSpectograms[cont].append(line.split(' ')[2].rstrip())
                indFilePathRead=indFilePathRead+1
                cont=cont+1

        else:
            if(len(line.split(' '))>=3):
                preictalSpectograms[cont].append(line.split(' ')[2].rstrip())
            indFilePathRead=indFilePathRead+1
```